# Is it possible to define covariancy/contravariancy in generic interface in C++/CLI?

Tags: c#, c++-cli

There is a nice [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) on covariancy and contravariancy in C#. Is it possible to implement such a covariant/contravariant interface in the C++/CLI?

Let's say that I have such a code in C#:

```cs
    interface IMyGeneric<out T> { }
    interface IMyOtherGeneric<out T> { }

    class MyGeneric<T> : IMyGeneric<T> { }
    class MyOtherGeneric<T> : IMyOtherGeneric<T> { }

    void Foo(IMyGeneric<IMyOtherGeneric<string>> arg) { }

    void Bar()
    {
        var mgs = new MyGeneric<MyOtherGeneric<string>>();
        Foo(mgs);
    }
```

How can I, or can I at all, implement it in C++/CLI?

Comment: @DarjanBogdan that's C++ - not C++/CLI; not sure that'll mean the same thing (as the question) in C++/CLI terms

Comment: @DarjanBogdan thanks for the link but this in deed is on C++ and not the C++/CLI. I've checked if there is some special syntax that could be applied in the C++/CLI but I've found none. Did I miss something?

Comment: Ah my bad, sry, didn't read the question properly :)